# Normal Unity3d UI buttons aren't working with Vufuria

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I made an AR game using Vuforia and everything is working fine except none of my UI buttons work. Not just the code too, they don't show any change what so ever when hovered above or clicked. The Button script is set to intractable, the colours are set and different. I also followed the normal steps to adding buttons to a canvas and code to buttons, but nothing works. In another app that has nothing to do with Vuforia, the buttons work fine, but the one in my AR game don't respond at all. I tried different scenes, different rendering modes, and different layers, but nothing works.

I'd really appreciate any help with this.

To add further info on the project, it's an android application, it does a specific action when the screen is clicked so when ever I test the button, instead of clicking that button it just does the action it normally does when the screen is clicked.

Comment: Can be many things? Are those screen or world canvas? Do you have the event system object in your scene? Would you have a ui item covering the screen? Does it work in editor?

Comment: @Evertsit's a screen canvas although I've tried it with the other settings too and it still doesn't work. Yes I have an Event System, The canvas is the only thing UI on the screen and the button is placed in front of everything else. No it doesn't work in the editor

Comment: The method is assigned in the listener of the button event?

Comment: Sorry, I actually found the source of the problem. It was something in the settings that had to do with raycast. Sorry I forgot to update this question. Thank you.